# Не устанавливается пакет webupd8team

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, deb, ppa

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему у меня не устанавливается пакет webupd8team?
Я проделываю следующие шаги:

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu focal main'
```

После этого пытаюсь установить данный пакет

```
sudo add-apt-repositore ppa:wepupd8team/tor-browser
```

После чего получаю ошибку:

```
Не удаётся добавить PPA: "'Данный PPA не поддерживает focal'"
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли эту ошибку как-то исправить? Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: Очевидно, что в данной репе нет поддержки твоей версии дистрибутива. Тебе надо писать не сюда, а разработчикам, чтобы они исправили ситуацию.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое